# Is it safe to share your ios development certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, iosdeployment

Is it safe to share the same iOS development certificate. Does it expose anything sensitive such as your private key.

The reason I am asking is because Apple seems to have a limit of 3 certificates, and we have quite a few freelance developers working for us.

Note that I am referring to a development certificate (NOT an app distribution certificate).

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The certificate proves bits are yours. The only way to ensure that nobody signs malware is not sharing the keys/certificates.

Comment: Even if its a development certificate? (Not a production one)

Comment: Does that also mean we need a separate certificate for every developer. If so, is there a way to get round the certificate limit problem?

Comment: If it's NOT the production certificates, feel free to share them. https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/